# What does "asm volatile("pushfl; popl %0" : "=r" (eflags))" mean? in assembly at c?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

now I try to understand xv6 code. and I found below code.

I think this code is related to assembly, but I couldn't find what it means.

especially, I found the front part of `asm volatile(:)` means assembly opeation set and what is the eflags, but I couldn't find what the back of this("=r" (eflags)) means.

So my question is.. what does the below code mean?
If you can give me some answer or advice, I'll really thank you for your sharing.
Thank you :)

```
static inline uint readeflags(void)
{
  uint eflags;
  asm volatile("pushfl; popl %0" : "=r" (eflags));
  return eflags;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your last question, the `"=r" (eflags)` part is the way in which one specifies in *GCC* inline assembly¹ what variable to use with a storage "location" and in what manner (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). Locations are numbered from 0, and multiple locations can be specified. `%0` hence being the first one.

`pushfl` pushes the contents of the `EFLAGS` register onto the stack, and `pop %0` removes the topmost value, i.e. the `EFLAGS` value and places it in location `%0`, which would be the `eflags` variable. It is done this way, because the IA-32 instruction set does not contain an instruction to read `EFLAGS` directly.

---

1: also used by LLVM, but not MSVC – inline assembly is not standardized!